# Stable Marriage problem variant that only cares about the preference of one party

Tags: algorithm, combinations, stable-marriage

I am looking for a variant of the stable marriage problem. That is, only one party has a preference for the other party. The other party must have no preference for the first party. An example: a set of people have a preference list for a set of committees. The committees, on the other hand, have no preference for the people that join them. Furthermore, all committees must have a distinct capacity.

My question is, does an algorithm to solve such a problem already exist? Or can the stable marriage problem be adapted such that it is compatible with my variant? I would prefer to see a programming library to implement my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do that by applying the stable mariage algorithm with a randomly generated list of preference for the second party.
That will make sure that if there are any collisions, you will still have a valid answer.